# How do I connect to an RDS sessionhost farm without DNSRR

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, session

I have an RDS deployment on Windows server 2012 R2.

There is 1 connection broker, which also has the RDWeb roles installed.

There are 2 session host servers; Lets call them shost1 and shost2.

I have set up the loadbalancing rules within the collection on the connection broker, but I cannot seem to find correct information on how I connect to these session hosts through the connection broker.

I can RDP to shost1 and shost2 individually, but I need my users to loadbalance between these two servers.

I don't want to set up RoundRobin DNS for this, as this will not take into account session host servers that are down for maintenance and it will not examine the load of the shost's, as far as I can tell.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Network Load Balancing comes to mind.

Comment: Is that literally it then? I use NLB on the cb to forward the traffic to the session hosts? will that still allow the connection broker to do its stuff?